# WCF RIA Services fail with authentication error if service call is more than 20 seconds

Tags: wcf, ria, windows-authentication

I have a Silverlight application which uses WCF RIA services and WindowsAuthentication mode.  When I deploy to our web server calls that are greater than 20 seconds in length seem to lose authentication and I get a dialog box from IE to re-enter my username and password.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

UPDATE:  I found out that the issue had nothing to do with what Fiddler was indicating and the authentication dialog was a side effect of another issue.

When I turned on WCF diagnostic tracing I found that what was really happening was that the service was throwing an exception due to the max number of items in graph.  My bindings in my web.config to override the service had an old service name so it was not picked up.

Based on this I would highly suggest that anyone having an issue turn on WCF diagnostic tracing on the web server and see what that says before following an error out of fiddler...

Thanks for the response to the post and your will to help out...

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be caused by the timeout issue, take a look at following link:

[receiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout.aspx)

Hope it help you. If it doesn't work, you may try to look at other timeouts, for example inactivityTimeout in reliable session.

Comment: I have the recieveTimeout up to five minutes and still fails after about 20 seconds or so sometimes faster sometimes longer.  When I look in fiddler I see that some of the 401 errors are getting automaticly renewed while others are not and that is when I get the dialog box.  This is sparadic as well.

Comment: Can you enable the trace on the server side and client side, and see what will happen?